# Why will she not take Pantea's Flute?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I found Pantea's Flute before the quest was given to me. Now she will not accept it from me, and it says I still need to go find it. What do I do now? Is this a glitch? I have the game on PC if that helps. I found a post about the lute in the same set of quests, but they just needed to get rid of the item while I need the item to complete the quest. So I don't think deleting it will help.

Comment: Sounds like the exact same problem I had with Finn's Lute: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44582/how-do-i-get-rid-of-finns-lute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug caused by retrieving the flute before the taking the quest. PC players might be able to fix by using

> setstage bardscollegeflute 40

Hope this helps :)

**Sources:** [Known Bug](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pantea%27s_Flute), [Fix](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Pantea%27s_Flute)

Comment: So what can I do to fix it? @Abeese you said you completed the quest but still had the lute. this old woman just keeps crying about the stolen flute and hot they don't know what is't worth. So I'm afraid that it I use a code to get ride of it than I can never finish the quest.

Comment: No problem! :) Glad I could help

Comment: Please put the actual answer in your post, not just a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

As for the console version (Xbox) i have still got the flute, drum and guitar (not sure of its real name) because i guess i picked them all up before the actual quest was initiated.

So i think in future references, just take a note on where they are, then get the quest active and then go and get them, because I've had to carry those items around all game and its rather annoying it taking up 10 weight for no reason.

So as far as finding a solution, i have none, just that get the quest active before picking the items up

hope this helps anyone else

thanks

Rob

Comment: Quest items do not count towards your total encumberance despite having a "weight" in your inventory.

Comment: oh cool, really, i didn't know that, thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Permanent bug if your saved game occurs before the patch is applied to the system. I should have waited for the patches before playing Skyrim. In general, the game is stable, but the few bugs in the game, are frustrating bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug for ps4. They were celebrating the burning of King Olaf and all she was doing was congratulating me. No dialog option. I forgot about it, went home right next door, spent some time and when I got out, I saw her walking towards Winking Skeewer. I wanted to try my luck again and this time a dialog option was there. I was able to gave her the flute. Before going home, I tried to pickpocket and place the flute by hand, which failed because it’s a quest item. I don’t know if this had any affect.