# Finn's Lute bug; Converting Xbox 360 save to PC to resolve

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360, pc

Playing Skyrim on Xbox 360. Ran into the Finn's Lute bug.

To resolve this, I'm thinking about taking my Xbox 360 save game file, converting it to a PC save game, entering in the PC console code: `setstage BardsCollegeLute 40`, then converting back to an Xbox 360 save game.

Has anyone done this? Would anyone advise against this?

Related posts/articles:

- [How do I get rid of Finn's Lute?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44582/how-do-i-get-rid-of-finns-lute/61953#61953)
- http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Finn%27s_Lute
- http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/copy-convert-your-skyrim-game-save-from-xbox-360-your-pc-0132217/
- [Convert save game to a different platform](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57205/convert-save-game-to-a-different-platform)

Note: I recognize that this process may be similar with another game, such as Mass Effect 3, but it's not the same. Similar, but not the same. This question has multiple elements:

- Can the saved game be successfully converted from Xbox 360 to PC?
- Can the saved game be successfully modified using the console code?
- Can the successfully modified game be converted back to Xbox 360, with changes intact?

Thus, I do not believe this question is duplicate. Though, I appreciate the chance to explain the question further.

Comment: That's specific to mass effect isn't it?

Comment: I understand the close vote as duplicate to the other [skyrim]-tagged question, but how is this a duplicate to a Mass Effect 3 question?

Comment: ...wasn't this one finally fixed in a recent patch?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, yes and no. If the character hasn't started the quest, or found the lute, then the quest has been fixed with the patch. Though, if the lute has already been found before the patch was applied, there is no fix, outside of the hack in question.

Comment: This just seems like an absurd amount of effort to get a 0 weight item out of your inventory list.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz. Good point. I won't disagree with you on that. It could seem absurd, but so can playing a video game for 100s of hours, or anything deemed as entertainment. I like Skyrim. I want to finish it, but annoying glitches detract from the experience.

Comment: About patch fixes: "*Please note that having a designated patch installed will not guarantee that the issue it was supposed to fix will be fixed upon entering game... As such it may be necessary to start a new game file to have all issues resolved.*" - http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Patch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The save file format used in Skyrim for Xbox, [once it has been extracted from the Xbox save file container file](http://justpressstart.net/how-to-swap-skyrim-saves-between-pc-and-xbox360/), is identical to the format used on PC and only needs its file extension changed from `.dat` to `.ess`. The game engines are also identical.

So the answers to your questions are yes, yes, and yes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link. I'll give it a shot. I'll let you know how it goes, fingers crossed.